# How to display one element based on whether there is such a value in the model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have a code like this:

```
<label>Manufacturer:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="B" /><span>B</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="C" /><span>C</span>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="D" /><span>D</span>
```

Input can be infinite.

How to check if the model has "brand" with a certain value? If there is, then output "input", if not, do not output.

I tried to do this, but it's dumb.

```
@model IEnumerable<BeautySouthKoreaSiteMVC.Models.Cosmetic>

@{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var b in Model)
    {
        if (b.Brand.Contains("A") && i == 0)
        {
            <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span>
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

The there is the model definition:

```
public class Cosmetic
{   
   [Display(Name = "Brand")]
   public string Brand { get; set; }

   // Some properties here...

}
```

Comment: If the `Brand` is collection (implementing `IEnumerable` interface) use `var result = Brand.FirstOrDefault(p => p == "A"); if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) {  <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span> }`

Comment: "The name "Brand" does not exist in the current context."

Comment: Sorry, `Model.Brand.FirstOrDefault(p => p == "A");` of course.

Comment: I've tried like this already. IEnumerable <Cosmetic> "does not contain a definition for" Brand "

Comment: Can you expose definition of the Model and of what is a type of the Brand, please? Does the view is strongly typed?

Comment: https://github.com/Betsq/SiteForSale . Model: "Cosmetic" ; View:  "_Goods"

Comment: `var result = Model.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Brand == "A"); if (result != null) {  <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span> }`. It is because of you `Model` is collection, not the `Brand`. Therefore checking that `result != null`.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, idea is using `FirstOrDefault()` with predicate on the collection:

```
@if (Model.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Brand == "A") != null) 
{
    <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="A" /><span>A</span> 
}
```